# sizeof an array passed as function argument

Tags: c++, recursion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [length of array in function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269048/length-of-array-in-function-argument)

Hi am doing homework and I am completly stumped.  We were suppose to get every order of a list an array of integers so I wrote this piece of code, based off of my teacher's pseudocode:

```
void permute(int v[], int curr,char letters[])
{
    if(curr >= sizeof(v)/sizeof(int))
    {
        checkit(v,letters);
    }
    for(int i = curr; i < sizeof(v)/sizeof(int); i++)
    {
        swap(i,curr,v);
        permute(v,curr + 1,letters);
        swap(v[curr],v[i]);
    }//for
}//permu
```

The only thing I am not sure of is if `sizeof(v)/sizeof(int)` is the right way to go.

Comment: If your question is only about `sizeof(v)/sizeof(int)`, I would suggest editing your question title, because it's nothing to do with "recursion for permutations"...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sizeof(v)/sizeof(int)` is not the way to go.  Your function is **exactly** equivalent to:

```
void permute(int *v, int curr, char *letters)
{
    ...
}
```

i.e. `v` is not really an array, it's a pointer.  You cannot pass arrays in C or C++.

The solution is one of the following (not exhaustive):

- add an extra argument that explicitly describes the length of the array
- add an extra argument that points at the last element of the array
- use a proper container (e.g. `std::vector`), which you can call `size()` on
- the template solution that @sehe suggests

Comment: +1 for containers, even though for homework they sometimes don't let you do it the "right" way.

Comment: I thought you could - permute(int n[5]) is fine? The array isnt quite passed by value. But it is an array

Comment: @Adrian: An array decays to a pointer when it's used as a function parameter.

Comment: @Oli can you point me at the paragraph in the standard that says that (doesnt matter which C99, C++98, C++03, C11). Would it be 8.3.4.8 in C++ in C98 for example? [Example: consider
int x[3][5];
Here x is a 3´5 array of integers. When x appears in an expression, it is converted to a pointer to (the first
of three) fivemembered
arrays of integers. In the expression x[i], which is equivalent to *(x+i), x is
first converted to a pointer as described; then x+i is converted to the type of x, which involves multiplying
i by the length of the object to which the pointer points, namely five...

Comment: @Adrian: C99, 6.3.2.1, paragraph 3: "Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or is a
string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is
converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’".

Comment: Just a thanks, I decided to go with a vector and it is working much better.

Answer (score 5):

One of my pet peeves: you can get C++ to deduce the array size for you

```
template <size_t N>
void permute(int (&v)[N], int curr,char letters[])
{
    if(curr >= N)
    {
        checkit(v,letters);
    }
    for(int i = curr; i < N; i++)
    {
        swap(i,curr,v);
        permute(v,curr + 1,letters);
        swap(v[curr],v[i]);
    }//for
}//permu
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Oli's answer: the typical way in C++ is to pass a pointer to the beginning and a pointer to the end of the sequence that you want to permute. By convention the beginning pointer is inclusive, the ending pointer is exclusive.

```
void permute(int *v, int *begin, int *end, char *letters) {
  if (begin == end) {
    checkit(v, end, letters);
  } else {
    ...
    permute(v, begin + 1, end, letters);
    ...
  }
}
```