# C - sizeof int array always returns 4

Tags: c, gcc, dev-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sizeof array of structs in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898657/sizeof-array-of-structs-in-c)
>   [sizeof an array passed as function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250829/sizeof-an-array-passed-as-function-argument)

Just trying to write a basic `sum()` function.

```
int sum(int arr[]) {
    int total = 0 , i = 0 , l = sizeof arr;

    for(i=0;i<l;i++) {
        total += arr[i];
    }

    return total;
}
```

`l` always equates to 4 (I know to eventually divide it by `sizeof int`)

Running Dev-C++ with default compiler options in Windows 7.

Comment: `arr` is a pointer, not an array. The syntax you use in the function declaration is just eye-candy for `int sum(int *arr)`. You might like to read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: compile on/for a 64 bit machine you should see 8 as you are looking at the size of the pointer not the size of the array.

Answer (score 11):

As function arguments, arrays decay to pointers to the element type, so `sizeof arr` is `sizeof(elem*)`.

You have to pass the number of elements as an extra argument, there is no way to determine that from the pointer to the array's first element (which is what is actually passed in that situation).

Comment: If the question contains '4', post 'sizeof(pointer)' <g>

Comment: How do I point to the array itself instead of the first element? Passing the length as a second argument is not a weakness a programmer should have to adapt to.

Comment: If you have `int arr[5];`, then `&arr` gives you a pointer to an array of five `int`, `int (*)[5]`. The address is, however, the same as `&arr[0]`, the address of the array's first element. What type of pointer you want depends on the situation. For summing the array elements, unless you want to have a different function for every size (`int sum_5(int (*)[5]);`, `int sum_6(int (*)[6]);`, you have to pass an `int*` and the number of elements. That's how C works.

Comment: @Daniel @dissident I don't see why you can't just use `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])`. It works for me.

Comment: @B1KMusic In a scope where `array` refers to an actual array, that works. But in `int sum(int arr[])`, the name `arr` does not refer to an array, it refers to an `int*`. So if you compute `sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]` in that function, you get `sizeof(int*) / sizeof(int)`.

Comment: ... http://pastebin.com/efSgH1fp

Comment: @B1KMusic Yes. In that, the names refer to actual arrays, so it _must_ work. Now add a `printf("%d\n", l);` to the `sum` function from the question, and call `sum(nums); sum(nums2); sum(nums3);`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then there really shouldn't be a problem just calculating the length in the scope where it's available and then passing it to the function.

Comment: Right, @B1KMusic. The only problem is that one must know that one has to do that.